# Is it possible build a native shared library from a jar which contains no main method or method annotated with @centrypoint

Tags: java, java-native-interface, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to convert an existing jar create using OpenJDK into a native shared library by using graal-vm 22's native-image tool. This jar does not have a main method or any static methods for that matter. I plan to use this generated shared library as dynamic dependency in another native image

I wasn't sure whether if it was even possible to build a shared library from a jar which doesn't have a main method or any other entrypoint method but this piece of documentation I'm [referring](https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/guides/build-native-shared-library/) seems to allow it:

```
If your library doesn’t include a main() method, use the -H:Name= command-line option to specify the library name, as follows:

native-image --shared -jar <jarfile> -H:Name=<libraryname>
```

However, even after after using this option I'm still getting `"Error: No main manifest attribute in jar"`

Any idea what changes I need to make in the jar or in the command to get this to work?